# What's the best practices to run a multi-tiers app as only one docker container?

Tags: docker

my app requires different services to run (each services has a corresponding Dockerfile either open source or that I maintain):

1. A database (run from [mariadb public docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mariadb))
2. An API (a JAR archive that I maintain; it' docker file being inherited from [openjdk public docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/openjdk))
3. A web client (a bunch of static HTML/CSS/JS that I maintain as well; it' docker file being inherited from  [public docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx))
4. Some other client that will be added down the road
5. A proxy to be the entry point of any request. (Directly run from [nginx public docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

Until now each block was defined by a docker image because i thought it would be the better way to run it (at least localy). Now that I have a working app, I'd like to be able to deploy it **as a single container in a docker-compose fleet**.

Here is how I tried to achieve that until now:
In my code base every one of the image I maintain (API and clients) are a git submodule of a parent master project. In that master project I had another Dockerfile inheriting from [docker compose public docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose). This master Image would hold the confs for other containers (as it's shared), start all the child via it's own compose file and mount the conf as volumes. This master image would be the one I (and other potential final users) later add to there compose file.

The problem with this approach is that all the child containers pop in the same compose environment as their parent, and instead of seeing only one more container (the master) added to the fleet I see a bunch.

Right now it seems their is no way to achieve exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'm thinking about starting the master image from scratch and make it install manually the database and all my services. But  with this approach I loose so much of the container advantages so I may have just missed the good way to achieve something like this.

Anyway if you have any tips to a better way to do so; or how to do it has I lastly mentioned but in a clean way I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best practice is to run it as the multiple containers that they already are. docker-compose can certainly handle this.

Comment: I think you missed part of the question or did not understood it correctly. I need only one container in the final compose. Basically running multiple container as only one, or destroying the current containers and creating only one main. Thanks for your time tho, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You asked for best practice. That is to stop trying to put everything in a single container.

Comment: I asked for best practice for a specific use case that you seems to ignore. Yes I have multiple services. No I don't want them to run as x containers. This is meant to keep the installation process easy. Let's take the Gitlab example; they provide docker image of their products. Do you think when you add a Gitlab to your fleet you need to import 100 containers (for git, postgres, the api, the web client, ect). No you don't because they package everything as ONE ONLY container. No if you have any revelant information please feel free to share it, but understand my goal before please.

Comment: Yes, and even they have recognized that this is the wrong approach, so [future versions](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/) will be split into separate containers.

Comment: I'll pay great attention to that documentation. But my app is meant to be run only for personal usage. Along side a lot of other services that are all similar. For exemple, there is Plex, Sonarr, Overseer, ect. End user just have to run a docker image and it works kind of a plug'n play. I recognize that it is not respecting the best practice 'no all in one container' and i accept that and it is final. Now my question is with this premise; what are the best practices or we can call them tips to achieve such a thing.